# Accessing Movieclip added by a different function in the same class?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, instance, movieclip

I can't seem to find an answer to this problem. I can't get the following to work:

```
public class Callbattle extends MovieClip
    {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import global.Globalvar;

    public var battlegraphics:Array = new Array();
    public function Battle()
    {



        var battlewindow:MovieClip = new Battlewindow() as MovieClip;
        battlegraphics.push(addChild(battlewindow));
        battlewindow.x = 4; 
        battlewindow.y = 248;

        var attackbutton:MovieClip = new Battlebutton() as MovieClip;
        battlegraphics.push(addChild(attackbutton));
        attackbutton.x = 192; 
        attackbutton.y = 255;

        attackbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Attackclicked);


    }

    public function Attackclicked(event:MouseEvent):void{
        battlegraphics[attackbutton].y = 248;
    }
```

}

I'm getting the error

> battlegraphics[attackbutton].y = 248;

Before trying this method of adding the movieclips to the array I was doing it like this with the same result:

```
public class Callbattle extends MovieClip
        {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import global.Globalvar;
public function Battle()
        {



            var battlewindow:MovieClip = new Battlewindow() as MovieClip;
            this.addChild(battlewindow);
            battlewindow.x = 4; 
            battlewindow.y = 248;

            var attackbutton:MovieClip = new Battlebutton() as MovieClip;
            this.addChild(attackbutton);
            attackbutton.x = 192; 
            attackbutton.y = 255;

            attackbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Attackclicked);

            while (Globalvar.battle == true){

                if (hero1turn == true){

                }
            }
        }

        public function Attackclicked(event:MouseEvent):void{
            attackbutton.y = 248;
        }
    }
```

I basically just want to be able to access a movieclip from another function.

Thanks heaps guys, any help would be amazing
-Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is, if you are referencing contents of an array, you use indexes of type `int`, or in some cases of type `String`, while your `attackbutton` is undefined in that function. The solution is pretty simple: declare `attackbutton` outside of `Battle()` function, and remove `var` from initiating `attackButton`.

```
public class Battle extends MovieClip {
    private var attackbutton:MovieClip;
    private var battlewindow:MovieClip;
    public function Battle() {
        attackbutton=new Battlebutton();
        battlewindow=new Battlewindow();
        ...
    }
    public function attackClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
        attackbutton.y=248; // this is now valid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

battlegraphics[**attackbutton**].y = 248;

Array should take number and not the variable name you specified.
So it will be

battlegraphics[1].y = 248;